# Generate Array of Role in response for Single User having multiple Roles in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

In Rails project, I am trying to generate array of Category's name if it belongs to Single User.

For example, User A have two categories like LandLord and PropertyBroker.

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :users_categories

  scope :users_categories_active, -> { joins(:users_categories)
                                       .where('users_categories.status = ?', true) }
  def self.with_selected_active_user
    select("users.id, users.first_name, users.city, categories.name,
                                           users_categories.status, users_categories.id")
  end
end
```

**Category Model**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_categories
  has_many :users, through: :users_categories
end
```

**UserCategory Model**

```
class UserCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
end
```

**Query**

```
user_list = User.joins(:categories, :users_categories)
                         .with_selected_active_user.users_categories_active.uniq
render :json => user_list
```

**Output**

```
[{"id":2,"first_name":"Adam","city":"Mumbai","status":true,"name":"LandLord"},
 {"id":3,"first_name":"Charles","city":"Delhi","status":true,"name":"Tenant"},
 {"id":1,"first_name":"Adam","city":"Mumbai","status":true,"name":"ProperyBroker"}
]
```

I am trying to generate this output in different patter

```
 [{"first_name":"Adam","city":"Mumbai","status":true,"name":"['LandLord','ProperyBroker'"},
 {"first_name":"Charles","city":"Delhi","status":true,"name":"Tenant"} 
 ]
```

To summarise, I'd like to put category name in one array.

Comment: This question appears to be old and abandoned, and is probably best closed and deleted. Rubyist, for future reference: when people help you, "not working" is rarely sufficient feedback to describe whether someone's suggestion worked or not. Remember that you are the eyes and ears for readers, and if you provide no feedback, then people helping you have nothing new to work with.

Comment: May be closed under: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_.

Answer (score 0):

Use `group` in your query, like below -

```
user_list = User.joins(:categories, :users_categories)
              .with_selected_active_user.users_categories_active.group(" first_name, city, status, name ")
render :json => user_list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[{"id" => 2,"first_name" => "Adam","city" =>"Mumbai","status" => true,"name" => "LandLord"},
 {"id" => 3,"first_name" => "Charles","city" => "Delhi","status" => true,"name" => "Tenant"},
 {"id" => 1,"first_name" => "Adam","city" => "Mumbai","status" => true,"name" => "ProperyBroker"}
].reduce({}) do |m, e|
  found = (m[e["city"]] ||= {status: e['status'], names: [], city: e['city']})
  found[:names] << e['name']
  m
end.values
```

=> [{:status=>true, :names=>["LandLord", "ProperyBroker"], :city=>"Mumbai"},
 {:status=>true, :names=>["Tenant"], :city=>"Delhi"}]